# Folders are stuck on the top left corner behind the launcher (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: display, directory

I have a strange problem where I couldn't find any help in the web so far. Unfortunately, I also do not really know what I have done, at some point it was just as follows:

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with the launcher on the left hand side. Whenever I open a folder, it appears on the top left corner in such a way that part of it is also hidden by the launcher. Even worse, the maximize, minimize and close symbols are gone and I am also unable to drag and drop them. I also have a screenshot here, which hopefully explains the situation better:

[image: Glitched Launcher]

Anybody having an idea what I have done and how to correct it? It is pretty inconvenient to work if all the folders are stuck in the corner (programmes like Firefox or so seem to be unaffected by that though).

Comment: If you press Alt+drag the window to another position, is it solved the next time you open nautilus?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution needs ccsm (CompizConfig Setting Manager):

1. Select Window Management
2. Select the check button "Place Windows"
3. Open the "Place windows" by clicking on the icon
4. Choose a "Placement Mode", default should be "Smart"